# How do I delete a ".jpeg" file without it turning into a ".REMOVE_ME" file

Tags: python, image, delete-file

So, I created a Python program to search images via Google's API, blur them, send them to Instagram,delete a .json file that kept raising an exception when launching the program multiple times, **and to delete all images of the folder to save space on my computer.** It looks like this, minus the keys and the Instagram part:

```
# Imports

from google_images_search import GoogleImagesSearch
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import random as ran
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Variables 

query = ran.choice(open("All EN Words.txt").readlines())
gis = GoogleImagesSearch("API key","Secret key")
dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Shitpost generator"
_search_params = {
'q': query,
'num': 1,
'fileType': 'jpg',
}

# Search

gis.search(search_params=_search_params, path_to_dir=dir, width=500, height=500)

# Hunt for last file, sorted by oldest to newest file

os.chdir(dir)
folder = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(dir))
folder = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in folder]
folder.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
image = folder[-1]

# Add text

img = Image.open(image)
font_size = ran.randint(25,200)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",font_size)
I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
h = ran.randint(0,(500-font_size))
try:
    b = ran.randint(0,(500-(font_size*len(query))))
except:
        b = 0
I1.text((b,h), query,font=font, fill=(ran.randint(0,255),ran.randint(0,255),ran.randint(0,255)))
img = img.convert("RGB")
img.save(image)

# Motion Blur

img = cv2.imread(image)
size = 15
kernel_motion_blur = np.zeros((size, size))
kernel_motion_blur[int((size-1)/2), :] = np.ones(size)
kernel_motion_blur = kernel_motion_blur / size
output = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel_motion_blur)
cv2.imwrite(image, output)

# Indiscriminally deletes the images, except the ".REMOVE_ME" files, within reason

for i in folder:
    os.remove(i)
```

I successfully coded all parts of it, but instead of deleting the images off the directory, my program makes ".REMOVE_ME" files, then raises an exception that the requested files aren't existant...
[".REMOVE_ME" files in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTtAy.png)

I tried to use "os.remove(folder[-1])" to erase the most recent file of the dir, so the one I've just posted, still transforms them into those lousy ".REMOVE_ME" files.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, solution was much simpler than I imagined:

```
for i in folder:
    try:
        os.remove(i)
    except:
        os.remove(i+".REMOVE_ME")
```